VSCode disable function parameter (intellisense?) markers (disable "inlay hints")
Today, out of nowhere, I am now seeing strange markers inside functions in VSCode. Ex: s1:, s2:, dest:, src:, etc.
What do s1 and s2 mean, and how do I turn this off?


When copying and pasting, these extra parts are not included, but here is what it would look like if typed manually to include them:
else if(!strcasecmp(s1: param, s2: "TASKLIST3"))

strcpy(dest: connection->buffer, src: protocolLinkName());

(I'm tagging both the C and C++ languages since if this is a plugin or setting it affects both.)
VSCode version is 1.88.1, on Linux Ubuntu 22.04:
From Help --> About --> Copy:
Version: 1.88.1
Commit: e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39
Date: 2024-04-10T17:34:12.840Z
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.5.0-27-generic


Update: here's the answer:
See: What are these parameter name annotations in my VS Code editor called, and how can I enable/disable them?.
They are called "inlay hints".
In short, to disable them:
Open settings with File --> Preferences --> Settings, then search for "inlay hints" and choose "offUnlessPressed" (my preference) to only see them when holding Ctrl + Alt, or choose "off" to disable them entirely. See screenshot:


These seem to be called inline hints. See How to disable Inline hints on VSCode? (Java) and What are these parameter name annotations in my VS Code editor called, and how can I enable/disable them?
